# Visualize data and clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, visualization

i am currently writing a python script to find the similarity between documents.I have already calculated the similarities score for each document pairs and store them in dictionaries. It looks something like this:

{(8328, 8327): 1.0, (8313, 8306): 0.12405229825691289, (8329, 8328): 1.0, (8322, 8321): 0.99999999999999989, (8328, 8329): 1.0, (8306, 8316): 0.12405229825691289, (8320, 8319): 0.67999999999999989, (8337, 8336): 1.0000000000000002, (8319, 8320): 0.67999999999999989, (8313, 8316): 0.99999999999999989, (8321, 8322): 0.99999999999999989, (8330, 8328): 1.0}

My final goal is to cluster the similar documents together. The data above can be viewed in another way. Let's say the document pair (8313,8306). The similarity score is 0.12405. I can specified that the inverse of the score will be the distance between document 8313 and 8306. Therefore, similar documents will cluster closer together while not-so-similar documents will be further apart based on their distance.

My question is, IS there any open source visualization tool that can help me to achieve this?

Comment: The question asks how to visualize a set of points given only pairwise distances, so we need a tool that can first calculate the best embedding of these points in the plane before we can actually plot their locations. As far as I can tell, none of the answers so far have explicitly addressed this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the term for that type of graph would be (minimum weight spanning tree?), but check out [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  There are some [Python bindings](http://code.google.com/p/yapgvb/) for it as well, but failing that you could simply generate an input file for it, or pipe data directly in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use MDS

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling

Comment: MDS is just an approach, you have to find an actual implementation...

Answer (score 0):

I think [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) can do this. You might have to massage the input file to a different format first. Weka also has an API, though it's in Java, not Python.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tools you can use to do this.

There have been other mentions, but you could fairly easily do something like this in Tkinter, PyGTK+, PyQT, matplotlib, or really *any* graphical lib.

However, a polar plot in [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html) would be fairly simple:

(untested):

```
import math
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show

# assign your data here
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

for pair in data:
    ax.plot(0, data[pair], 'o')
show()
```

That should give you a rudimentary visualization. You could also change it around to

```
ax.plot(pair*math.pi, 1, 'o')
```

For a different style of visualization.

The matplotlib docs are very good and they have plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Networkx may help. This example could be a good starting point:

http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/drawing/knuth_miles.html